# Is there a limit in the amount of temporary generated symbols during a project build using dmd 2.063?

Tags: compiler-construction, d, dmd

Is there a limit in the amount of temporary generated symbols during a project build using dmd 2.063?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit is in the backend: it's possible to instantiate 99999 temporaries right now.

If you need more, you can raise the 'name' declaration in symbol_generate function in symbol.c, and recompile dmd.

I'm having the same issue with 2.063.2 right now!

Answer (score 4):

It's an overflow bug in the compiler.

Bug report: http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=10735

Fix: https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/dmd/pull/2438